# Evaluating limits, can someone check my answer

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

Evaluate

$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty }  x + \dfrac{1}{x}$

$=\dfrac{x}{x}$ + $\dfrac{1/x}{x}$

$=1+1$

$=2$

I think my answer is correct but i just need a second opinion.

Comment: Second opinion: No, it is not correct.

Comment: @user You have $h \to \infty$ but the expression is in terms of $x$. Is this correct or did you mean $x \to \infty$?

Comment: $ \lim_{x \to \infty} (x) $ is not $1$.

Comment: Is it possible that the limit is actually $x\to 1$?

Comment: I think @vadim123 has it right.. Are you sure you're taking $x \to \infty$ rather than $x \to 1$? The lines of math symbols written seems like a Mad Lib at this point.. do some edits need to happen?

Comment: Nope it is $x→∞$. I edited the post to show how i got the answer.

Comment: Errors: 1. You can't just divide by $x$.  2. $\frac{1/x}{x}=\frac{1}{x^2}\neq 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \left( x + \dfrac {1}{x} \right) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left( x \right) + \lim_{x \to \infty} \left( \dfrac {1}{x} \right) = \infty + 0 = \boxed {\infty}. $$
Alternatively, you can add the fractions (kind of overkill) and find: $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \left( x + \dfrac {1}{x} \right) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \left( \dfrac {x^2+1}{x} \right). $$From here, we see that the degree of the numerator is $2$ but that of the denominator is $1$, so it will tend to infinity. If you want, you can use l'Hôpital's Rule and find: $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \left( \dfrac {2x}{1} \right) = \boxed {\infty}. $$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{x} \to 0, x \to \infty$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} x + \frac{1}{x} = \infty + \frac{1}{\infty} = \infty + 0 = \infty$$